# Strange characters when call messagebox function from DLL file?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I see a problem when call function from dll file which compiled in C++, dll file with functions code as follow:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* str;
int _stdcall inputt(char* str_)
{
    str=str_;
    return 1;
}

int _stdcall Shooow()
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL,str,"Message...",MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

In this, I export two function inputt() and Shooow(). Dll file named "TestCCCC.dll". Then I call them in C# code as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace muWrapper
{
    public partial class WndSample : Form
    {
        [DllImport("TestCCCC.dll")]
        private static extern int inputt(string FuncName);
        [DllImport("TestCCCC.dll")]
        private static extern int Shooow();

      public WndSample()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          int ret = inputt("aaaaaa");
          ret = Shooow();
      }
    }
}
```

When I run it, click the button with the first time, it show a message box with strange characters, not "aaaaaa" !!!? Continue to click with the second time, it show truly with "aaaaaa", and continue...and show truly and truly....

Tell me what was happen in this problem? How to code two function inputt() and Shooow() to show truly at the first time? Thanks.

Comment: Not too sure, but it could be the default characters in the buffer, the second time is your first click. To test, I suggest you put a running number `1`, `2`, `3`, etc to see if the guess is correct.

Comment: You're retaining a pointer to a temporary string. If you want to use it later, you'll have to copy the string.

Comment: When sending strings to a dll and back use a byte[] and terminate end of characters with '\0';  Standard c doesn't support the string class which contains two byte characters.

Comment: Hi Lan, I'm sure about this.

Comment: @RaymondChen: How can I do this? Thanks. Really, I dont understand it. Hope you help me.

Comment: @jdweng: Really, I want you to show me clearly about this? Thanks.

Comment: string input = "Hello World";
            byte[] str = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + "\0");

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. I have a solution, but I'm trying that your solution above. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn more about manual memory management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inputt` is passed a pointer to a temporary string.  You can't just save the pointer, you'll need to save a copy of the whole string.  Easiest to do that with `std::string`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

static std::string str;
int _stdcall inputt(const char* str_)
{
    str=str_;
    return 1;
}

int _stdcall Shooow()
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL,str.c_str(),"Message...",MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

C# natively supports Unicode strings.  If you want to handle arbitrary strings, you will need to change the DLLImport line to:

```
    [DllImport("TestCCCC.dll", CharSet = Unicode)]
    private static extern int inputt(string FuncName);
```

and then change the C++ to:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

static std::wstring str;  // wide string
int _stdcall inputt(const wchar_t* str_) // wide char pointer.
{
    str=str_;
    return 1;
}

int _stdcall Shooow()
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL,str.c_str(),L"Message...",MB_OK);  // Use W version and long title.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's my solution.